# Determine position of element in list with low time complexity

Tags: python

I do the following

```
L = [[1], [2], [3], [1,2], [2,3], [1,2,3]]
L1, L2, L3 = [], [], []
for x in L:
    if len(x) == 1:
        L1.append(x)
    elif len(x) == 2:
        L2.append(x)
    elif len(x) == 3:
        L3.append(x)
```

and I would like to then be able to as an example

```
for x in L3:
    for i in range(len(x)):
        Determine the position of x[:i] + x[i+1:] in L2
```

and determine the position of `x[:i] + x[i+1:]` in `L2` in O(1)?

I could of course use a dictionary

```
L = [[1], [2], [3], [1,2], [2,3], [1,2,3]]
L1, L2, L3 = [], [], []
pos = {}
for x in L:
    if len(x) == 1:
        pos[tuple(x)] = len(L1)
        L1.append(x)
    elif len(x) == 2:
        pos[tuple(x)] = len(L2)
        L2.append(x)
    elif len(x) == 3:
        pos[tuple(x)] = len(L3)
        L3.append(x)

for x in L3:
    for i in range(len(x)):
        pos[x[:i] + x[i+1:]]
```

however, the lists that I work with are huge so I would prefer if I could avoid converting the list to a tuple.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Well, you only need to make a dictionary out of `L1`.  And if there's really only one item, then skip the tuple and use `x[0]` as the key.  Is your data actually small integers?  You could use a fixed-size list as a lookup.

Comment: Sorry, the problem formulation was wrong initially

Comment: If you know they are integers and you have many, use a B-Tree? Or use some database like SQL if the creation does not create too much overhead, the lookup will be fast.

Comment: They are integers and I need to be able to run the last loop four any list Lx (where x denotes the number of elements in the lists)

Comment: Is your actual data so well ordered? If it is, surely you could use that structure to figure out the position.

Comment: BTW, welcome back to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: You should describe your problem in English, not just showing the code. Anyway, what about using tuples instead of lists from the beginning, if your lists of integers are immutable? It's unavoidable to create a mapping structure from a list of integers to an integer, regardless of whether it's a hash, tree or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I created a dictionary to store the lists by their length.
Then we create sublists from the lists of length 3 to check if they exist in the lists of length 2.

```
list_of_lists = [[1], [2], [3], [1, 2], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]

sublists_by_len = {}
for item in list_of_lists:
    key = len(item)
    if key not in sublists_by_len:
        sublists_by_len[key] = []
    sublists_by_len[key].append(item)

for some_list in sublists_by_len[3]:
    for i in range(len(some_list)):
        concatenated_list = some_list[:i] + some_list[i + 1 :]
        if concatenated_list in sublists_by_len[2]:
            print(
                f"found list {concatenated_list} at index" 
                f"{sublists_by_len[2].index(concatenated_list)}"
        )
        else:
            print(f"list {concatenated_list} not found")
```